# Multiple-redirects between index.html and index.php in wordpress - htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

So this is my situation:

- I have one wordpress instance running on multisite with 3 subdomaine (3 sites)
- I only need wordpress on those 3 sub-sites, for main-domain index I have a    different index.html that I need to use

So may question is: how ca I redirect domain.com to index.html, but keep blog.domain.com & jobs.domain.com (etc) using index.php from Wordpress?

Thank you in advance.